# Zeppelin under Mesos - Initial job has not accepted any resources

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, mesos, dcos

Trying to run queries with zeppelin on Mesos cluster, using Cassandra as the data source.

I was able to run it in DEV environment, but when taking the same configuration and packages to prod, it's not working.

I'm using below code to bring the table structure, and this one is passing:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

val state = sparkSession.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map("keyspace" -> "someKeySpace", "table" -> "someTable")).load() state.createOrReplaceTempView("state")
```

In next paragraph running the query:

```
%sql

select 1 from state
```

the task just hangs, running with 0% and nothing is happening, when trying to debug I get the following in the interpreter log, I gave enough CPU/Mem resources and all NW traffic is enabled master/slaves

```
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:43,915] ({dispatcher-event-loop-15} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - parentName: default, name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:44,915] ({dispatcher-event-loop-0} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - parentName: default, name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:45,915] ({dispatcher-event-loop-2} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - parentName: default, name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:46,553] ({Thread-436} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - Received 2 resource offers.
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:46,553] ({Thread-436} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - Declining offer: 7ed1dd50-6efe-422d-913c-4835a3db28f4-O22973 with attributes: Map() mem: 32218.0 cpu: 2.9 port: List((1025,2180), (
2182,3887), (3889,5049), (5052,6999), (7002,7198), (7200,8079), (8082,8180), (8182,9000), (9002,9041), (9043,9159), (9161,9599), (9601,27059), (27061,32000))
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:46,553] ({Thread-436} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - Declining offer: 7ed1dd50-6efe-422d-913c-4835a3db28f4-O22974 with attributes: Map() mem: 50650.0 cpu: 10.9 port: List((1025,2180),
(2182,3887), (3889,5049), (5052,6999), (7002,7198), (7200,8079), (8082,8180), (8182,9000), (9002,9041), (9043,9159), (9161,9599), (9601,14175), (14177,32000))
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:46,915] ({dispatcher-event-loop-1} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - parentName: default, name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:47,915] ({dispatcher-event-loop-4} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - parentName: default, name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:48,232] ({Thread-437} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - Received 1 resource offers.
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:48,232] ({Thread-437} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - Declining offer: 7ed1dd50-6efe-422d-913c-4835a3db28f4-O22977 with attributes: Map() mem: 37338.0 cpu: 4.9 port: List((1025,2180), (
2182,3887), (3889,5049), (5052,6999), (7002,7198), (7200,8079), (8082,8180), (8182,8999), (9002,9041), (9043,9159), (9161,9599), (9601,20592), (20597,32000))
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:48,915] ({dispatcher-event-loop-3} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - parentName: default, name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:49,915] ({dispatcher-event-loop-6} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - parentName: default, name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:50,915] ({dispatcher-event-loop-5} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - parentName: default, name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0 
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:51,915] ({dispatcher-event-loop-7} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - parentName: default, name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:52,241] ({Thread-438} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - Received 2 resource offers.
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:52,241] ({Thread-438} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - Declining offer: 7ed1dd50-6efe-422d-913c-4835a3db28f4-O22979 with attributes: Map() mem: 32218.0 cpu: 2.9 port: List((1025,2180), (
2182,3887), (3889,5049), (5052,6999), (7002,7198), (7200,8079), (8082,8180), (8182,9000), (9002,9041), (9043,9159), (9161,9599), (9601,27059), (27061,32000))
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:52,241] ({Thread-438} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - Declining offer: 7ed1dd50-6efe-422d-913c-4835a3db28f4-O22980 with attributes: Map() mem: 50650.0 cpu: 10.9 port: List((1025,2180),
(2182,3887), (3889,5049), (5052,6999), (7002,7198), (7200,8079), (8082,8180), (8182,9000), (9002,9041), (9043,9159), (9161,9599), (9601,14175), (14177,32000))
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:52,915] ({dispatcher-event-loop-8} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - parentName: default, name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:53,243] ({Thread-439} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - Received 1 resource offers.
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:53,243] ({Thread-439} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - Declining offer: 7ed1dd50-6efe-422d-913c-4835a3db28f4-O22982 with attributes: Map() mem: 37338.0 cpu: 4.9 port: List((1025,2180), (
2182,3887), (3889,5049), (5052,6999), (7002,7198), (7200,8079), (8082,8180), (8182,8999), (9002,9041), (9043,9159), (9161,9599), (9601,20592), (20597,32000))
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:53,915] ({dispatcher-event-loop-9} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - parentName: default, name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:54,915] ({dispatcher-event-loop-10} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - parentName: default, name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:55,915] ({dispatcher-event-loop-11} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - parentName: default, name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:56,915] ({dispatcher-event-loop-12} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - parentName: default, name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:57,251] ({Thread-440} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - Received 2 resource offers.
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:57,252] ({Thread-440} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - Declining offer: 7ed1dd50-6efe-422d-913c-4835a3db28f4-O22986 with attributes: Map() mem: 32218.0 cpu: 2.9 port: List((1025,2180), (
2182,3887), (3889,5049), (5052,6999), (7002,7198), (7200,8079), (8082,8180), (8182,9000), (9002,9041), (9043,9159), (9161,9599), (9601,27059), (27061,32000))
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:57,252] ({Thread-440} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - Declining offer: 7ed1dd50-6efe-422d-913c-4835a3db28f4-O22987 with attributes: Map() mem: 50650.0 cpu: 10.9 port: List((1025,2180),
(2182,3887), (3889,5049), (5052,6999), (7002,7198), (7200,8079), (8082,8180), (8182,9000), (9002,9041), (9043,9159), (9161,9599), (9601,14175), (14177,32000))
DEBUG [2018-10-29 10:25:57,915] ({dispatcher-event-loop-13} Logging.scala[logDebug]:58) - parentName: default, name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
WARN [2018-10-29 10:25:58,182] ({Timer-0} Logging.scala[logWarning]:66) - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resource
```

Comment: Do you have correct IP-address/hostname for the `spark.cassandra.connection.host` configuration property? See https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md

Comment: yes of course, cassandra properties already there. I was even able to retrieve the table schema, but no queries

Comment: Can you add information about versions of spark Cassandra connector and Zeppelin? I’ve used it without problems

Comment: sure,
spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.0.1.jar
zeppelin:0.7.3-2-all-2.2.1-1-hadoop-2.6

by the way, with the same artifacts i was able to run it too including queries in my DEV environment, but it's not working for me on customer environments

Comment: It's hard to say from logs. Everything looks OK. We should add the reason why offers are declined in log message. If it was working on DEV then can you show your configuration of Mesos and Spark?